# link html files under public folder when using vuepress

Tags: vuepress

I am using vuepress to build a personal notes.
I put some html, javascript demo files inside `.vuepress/public/demo/javascript/01/`.

When I writing my note using in `.md` file, I create a link by `[demo](/demo/javascript/01/)`

this seems not work well cause such relative path, vuepress will treat it as a `.md` file and try to look for the path and result as `404`
(Although do a `refresh` on the 404 page, it works well..)

What is the better way to link files under public which I can use in `.md` and make vuepress treat it as normal external link without hardcoding the domain in the link.

here is the code
https://gitlab.com/changsijay/vuepress01

and here is the deployment result:
https://changsijay.gitlab.io/vuepress01/

Answer (score 0):

I would move your code from `index.html` to a .vue-file and add the vue file to your index.html (except, I would name it `README.md`, [since that is what VuePress looks for in every sub-directory](https://vuepress.vuejs.org/guide/markdown.html#links)) with the basic vue syntax `<IndexCode />`.

Then just link with `[demo](/demo/javascript/01/)` and it should automatically load the `README.md`

If for some reason you want to use the `index.html`, you can always link it with `[demo](/demo/javascript/01/index.html)`